# Getting the value of an animating property

Tags: iphone, animation

I am animating a simple UIView transform and would like to be able to access the values of the transform during the animation.

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];

```
CGAffineTransform rot=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);
CGAffineTransform scale=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 4.0f/3.0f);
viewFinder.transform=CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, rot);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However when I commit the animation and start querying viewFinder.transform.a I get the initial value and then only after the end of the animation do i get the updated version.
So I have a feeling that CoreAnimation is storing a separate transform on its animation stack and animating that. Anyone know how to get hold of the transform during the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solved it. Bit tricky and feels like a hack but it works

I query this in a method repeatedly called by an NSTimer

```
CGAffineTransform rot =[viewFinder.layer.presentationLayer affineTransform];
```

I imagine one can do the same for any other property